# Eclipse custom texteditor - marker annotation presentation issue

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations, markers, text-editor

I want to write an eclipse plugin for my computer science lecturer. It's a custom editor with an xml based file format.
I've implemented syntax highlighting and other stuff. But I stuck when it comes to the usage of annotations/marker to show invalid content.

This is how it looks like, if the content is valid:

[image of valid conent http://image-upload.de/image/aPcsaa/6c799a671c.png](http://image-upload.de/image/aPcsaa/6c799a671c.png)

This is how it looks like, if the content is invalid:

[image of invalid conent http://image-upload.de/image/4TdooQ/04d662f397.png](http://image-upload.de/image/4TdooQ/04d662f397.png)

As you can see, invalid attributes will get marked, but the problem is, the whole formatting seems to be lost between these annotations.

I use `org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.Reconciler` for delayed parsing of the content to create the document model. The model is used to format the text and display annotations. All this happens in the void `void process(DirtyRegion dirtyRegion)` method of the `Reconciler`.

For text formatting I use `<ITextViewer>.changeTextPresentation(textAttributes, false)` and for annotation handling I use

```
IAnnotationModel annotationModel = <ISourceViewer>.getAnnotationModel();
IAnnotationModelExtension annotationModelExtension = (IAnnotationModelExtension) annotationModel;
annotationModelExtension.replaceAnnotations(oldAnnotations, newAnnotations);
```

Since the `Reconciler` does not use the swt thread I have to use this construct to avoid exceptions:

```
<ITextViewer>.getTextWidget().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {

    <ITextViewer>.changeTextPresentation(textAttributes, false);
    updateAnnotations(nodes);
  }
});
```

By the way `ITextViewer` and `ISourceViewer` are meant as the same *viewer object*.

As annotation type I've testet: `org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.spelling` and some others, also custom types, but all with the same result.

I'm not quite sure, what I do wrong, could it be because it is all in a single call?

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there no-one, who can help me? Or do you need some more information about the used source code and classes?